# Black space on right side of pdfDocument generated using PrintDocumentAdapter

Tags: android, printing, pdfdocument

I am printing contents on an interface inside a scrollview using PrintDocumentAdapter. The final result, however, has black space on right side of the generated document. There is no such blank space on actual interface.

```
  public void printScrollViewContent() {
    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
    String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

    printManager.print(jobName, new PrintDocumentAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {
        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
          callback.onLayoutCancelled();
          return;
        }

        // Get the dimensions of the scroll view
        int height = scrollView.getHeight();

        // Get the total size of the content in the scroll view
        int totalHeight = scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();

        // Calculate the number of pages needed
        numberOfPages = (int) Math.ceil((double) totalHeight / height);

        Rect pageDimensions = new Rect();
        scrollView.getDrawingRect(pageDimensions);

        // Prepare the PDF document layout
        PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("print_output.pdf");
        builder.setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
            .setPageCount(numberOfPages);

        PrintDocumentInfo info = builder.build();
        callback.onLayoutFinished(info, true);
      }

      @Override
      public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {
        // Render content and write to PDF document
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
          PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(scrollView.getWidth(), scrollView.getHeight(), i).create();
          PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);
          Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

          // Calculate the portion of the content to be drawn for this page
          int start = i * canvas.getHeight();
          int end = Math.min((i + 1) * canvas.getHeight(), scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight());

          // Create bitmap of the portion of the scroll view content for this page
          Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scrollView.getWidth(), end - start, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

          Canvas contentCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
          contentCanvas.translate(0, -start); // Translate canvas to the appropriate position

          scrollView.getChildAt(0).draw(contentCanvas);

          // Draw the bitmap onto the canvas
          canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

          // Finish the page
          pdfDocument.finishPage(page);
        }

        try {
          // Write the PDF document to the output stream
          pdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          pdfDocument.close();
        }

        callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{new PageRange(0, numberOfPages - 1)});
      }
    }, null);
  }
```

| Actual Interface | Generated PDF |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

I tried playing around with x index of the canvas but it did not help. The right space remains there. I need help figuring how to fix the extra blank space on right in the generated PDF. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a lot of over complication and probably won't produce the best results and seem to ignore all the reasons to use a PrintAdaptor instead of just writing the PDF as a file.

But I don't think that is the cause of the issue.

It's most likely because you size the bitmap and pdf page to a different thing to what you actually draw.

The bitmap and pdf page are sized to `scrollView.getWidth()` but then you draw `scrollView.getChildAt(0)`  these two items are not necessary the same width.

I would try sizing the pdf and bitmap to the thing you actually draw e.g. `scrollView.getChildAt(0).getwidth()`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using `scrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth()` as width of PdfDocument and bitmap makes no difference. There is still a space on right side of interface as in my original question.

Comment: It is very difficult to help without details of all the views are created, it helps if you add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Here is another way of generating at pdf https://github.com/Zardozz/RecyclerviewPdf, this is for a recyclerview but the concept of iterating through the children of scrollView.getChildAt(0) is the same as iterating through the recyclerview items.

Comment: Creating a minimal reproducible is taking more than I anticipated. I tried hard coding  the value of height for PdfDocument builder and after trial and error came up with a value that renders the pages without any blank space on right. I think what was happening before was that height was much more than width and it caused contents to shrink so to fit the PdfDocument page. Working to now find a way to make the hard coded height dynamic. Tried calculating the visible part of scrollview and use it as height but it does not give consistent results.